# correct way to structure complex forms in HTML

Tags: html, css, forms, post

This is driving me insane, hours of googling and RTFM'ing did not help either. I need to know how experts would handle a form which is spread across multiple divs. My first choice was to just put a form around all the divs like so, and then resort to prayer:

**code ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/4AJnt/1/)):**

```
<div class='A'>
   <form id='fooForm' method='post' action='foo.php'>
      <div class='B1'>
         ...
      </div>
      <div class='B2'>
         <div class='B2-1'>
            ...
         </div>
         <div class='B2-2'>
            ...
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

but this results in everything being clumped together

**result:**
[image]

What I decided to do instead was to move the form out into a dummy form and deal with updating the values later and use the `jquery.submit` approach, like so:

**code ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pukster/mzBKw/1/)):**

```
<div class='A'>
   <div class='B1'>
      ...
   </div>
   <div class='B2'>
      <div class='B2-1'>
         ...
      </div>
      <div class='B2-2'>
         ...
      </div>
      ... 
   </div>
</div>
<form id='fooForm' method='post' action='foo.php'>
</form>
```

This now looks the way I want it to look

**result:**
[image]

but now I have to go through and create all the values either by creating dummy `input` and `select` elements and updating their values everytime the user makes changes, or do this at the end just before calling `form.submit`. My question whether it would be possible to just use jQuery's `post()` method to simulate the functionality of a form? I understand forms provide the benefit of automatically packaging and sending the values to the server, but they are just too darn restrictive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be possible, you can sent with $.post() whatever you want, strictly speaking you don't need even a form element, just pass the right data object to the function.

If you still what to use a proper form you can use first jquery serialize method to get values from inputs. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: This might come across as noobish, but will this cause a page refresh? Currently when my form is submitted the page is updated to reflect the choices made, and this is carried out serverside (php).

Comment: No, $.post() is a shortcut for $.ajax() with post method, which is obvious is ajax request. If you need to refresh the page just reload it manually window.location.reload()

Comment: it really strikes me as a different, not easier or harder, way of dealing with forms. In the end I just went with a hidden form since my PHP code was altering the HTML dynamically based on the post variables.

Answer (score 0):

As of structuring is concerned use html **lists** to structure everything inside a form.

```
<form id="form1" >
<ul>
<li><input /></li>
<li><select></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

then submit the form using **form serialization** by using jquery ajax that sends all form elements to server.

and to prevent refreshing of your page use `event.preventDefault()`

**Code:**

```
$('#submit').on("click",function(event) {
event.preventDefault( );
$.post("url",$('#form-id').serialize( ),function(data){}); }
}
```

Comment: I don't think lists give me the same control as divs. Also, I want it to refresh as my HTML pages are generated dynamically.